# I want to retrieve all the records from a table which were posted 24 hours back using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to retrieve all the records from a table which were posted 24 hours back using php mysql.
I can able to get last 24 hour inserted records using datetime column. But i want the records which were inserted into table and completed 24 hours from posting.

Please guys help me out!

Comment: update you question add  your table schema, a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "date" is your datetime column and "mytable" is your table

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```